# Split polygon by string length Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas

I'm new to GIS data manipulation. I have a WKT file with polygons. The geometry column is too large for the database and makes it impossible to query. How would I split the polygons and limit the character size to 30,0000 characters for example.

Example:

```
wkt,                   name
Polygon((0 1), (1 2)), DC
```

I want this to become

```
wkt,              name
Polygon((0 1))    DC
Polygon((1 2))    DC
```

I've tried exploding the polygon using GeoPandas.

```
myshpfile = geopandas.readfile("tl_2019_us_cbsa.shp")
gd = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(myshpfile)    
exploded = gd.explode(index_parts=True)
```

This converted the mulitpolygons in the shapefile to polygons, but some of the polygons were still too large. Is there a way to check the string count of the polygon and break it in half when it's over 30,000. The split does not need to be super precise.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. We are a *problem-solving* site, so I suggest you [Edit] the Question to detail what you tried with GeoPandas (exact code) and specify how it "didn't work." Note that you **can't** split the holes out of a polygon and retain any semblance of data quality, and that overlaying a grid on the features increases the total size of all polygons.

Comment: [Simplifying](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.simplify.html) the geometries would be an easy way of reducing geometry complexity.

Comment: Thanks @BERA! I was able to figure it out using simplification and this allowed to reduce the amount of vertices in the polygon which reduced the string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Simplifying](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.simplify.html) the geometries is an easy way of reducing geometry complexity.

But if you want to split: You can create a bounding rectangle around each polygon that should be split, move one of the short sides of the rectangle to the centroid of the rectangle. Then use the line to split the polygon.

[image]

I only split once. You can repeat the process until you reach the desired char count.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely import LineString
from shapely.ops import split

df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/multipoly.geojson")
#print(df.shape)
#(5, 2)
df = df.explode(column="geometry", index_parts=True)
#print(df.shape)
#(9, 2)

df["vertexcount"] = df.apply(lambda x: len(x.geometry.wkt), axis=1)

df_no_split = df.loc[df["vertexcount"]<2000].copy() #A df of polygons not to split
df_yes_split = df.loc[df["vertexcount"]>=2000].copy() #Polygons that should be split

def splitit(geometry):
    #Create a bounding rectangle
    rectangle = geometry.minimum_rotated_rectangle
    corner_vertices = list(rectangle.boundary.coords)
    rectcent = rectangle.centroid
    
    #Create lines of the four sides of the rectangle
    lines = [LineString([p1, p2]) for p1, p2 in zip(corner_vertices, corner_vertices[1:])]
    
    #Find a short side
    short_side = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x.length)[0]
    
    #Offset it to the center of the rectangle
    offset_distance = short_side.centroid.distance(rectcent) #What is the distance to the centroid of the rectangle
    
    #Offset the line in both direction then find which side offset the line to the rectangle centroid
    offset_lines = [short_side.parallel_offset(distance=offset_distance, side="right"), 
                    short_side.parallel_offset(distance=offset_distance, side="left")]
    centerline = sorted(offset_lines, key=lambda x: x.distance(rectcent))[0]
    split_polygon = list(split(geometry, centerline).geoms) #Split the polygon by the centerline
    return split_polygon #Return the list of split polygon parts

df_yes_split["geomlist"] = df_yes_split.apply(lambda x: splitit(x.geometry), axis=1) #Create a list of split geometries
df_yes_split = df_yes_split.explode(column="geomlist", index_parts=True)
df_yes_split["geometry"] = df_yes_split["geomlist"]

#Concatenate the two dataframes
result = gpd.pd.concat([df_no_split, df_yes_split])
result = result.drop(columns=["geomlist", "vertexcount"]).reset_index(drop=True)
result["newid"] = range(result.shape[0])

result.to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/multipoly_SPLIT.shp")
```

Three polygons had >=2000 characters in the wkt string and were split:

[image]